# Hanging knee raises on Short pull-up bar/ form

Tags: abdominals, home-exercise

I am curious how to do hanging knee raises on a short pull up bar in a home gym. I've read that although your arms are engaged, they should be extended. Naturally even a pull-up bar at 7 feet high doesn't do it for a 5'11 person. I have seen two variations on how to do this exercise. One is the classic "start from a dead hang then do a rep then return with your legs at the bottom(although engaged)". The second is from arnold schwarzeneggers book which he says to start with your knees bent at 90 degrees and start with legs in front of your body. You then do a rep, then return with your knees in front of your waist rather than returning your legs all the way to a dead hang. Is there a difference between these two variations, and can the arnold method be used on this short pull up bar? If not, is there a way to do these? I am not able to let my legs dangle all the way down and I feel like I'm doing an incomplete rep?

Comment: Just hold your chin over the bar and then it doesn't matter if the bar is low. :D Two workouts for the price of one! (I'm only half joking- I actually do this sometimes. Usually my arms give out before the rest of me though...)

Comment: Have you tried the two different starting positions? I just tried both (with keeping my knees bent the entire time) and I felt like starting from the "sitting" position was harder. It might be because of the natural inclination to rest for a fraction of a second between reps, which you can do when hanging, but you can't do when knees out front.

Comment: @TTT so would you suggest knees bent, lowering your legs all the way down, or starting from the sitting position and just going from "knees to chest" - to - "sitting"?

Comment: When hanging from a bar where my feet would touch the floor, I typically keep my knees bent the entire time and rotate my legs between parallel and perpendicular to the floor. Sometimes I do a 4 second count which is 1: knees up parallel to floor, 2: straighten legs parallel to the floor, 3: knees bent again (same as position 1), 4: legs back down with knees still bent. This is *significantly* harder and I can't do nearly as many reps. Ultimately, you should be able to tell if your ab workout is working for you. Keep mixing it up. :)